# Looking for the japanese word for "cat collar"

Tags: word-requests

I'm searching for the word for this, a kind of cat collar accessory [image]
I've searched everywhere, ask to many people but just found it in Korean but not in japanese.

Thank you for you help

Comment: 「シュシュ首輪」とかかな。。。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

首輪(kubiwa) is the name of a regular collar (to restrain and identify).

What you have shown a picture of is a neck decoration, or 首飾り(kubikazari).

If you search for [猫の首飾り](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E7%8C%AB%E3%81%AE%E9%A6%96%E9%A3%BE%E3%82%8A&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS734US734&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=lFfJ2b5YlQ132M%253A%252CgZWP_0_mM0JzzM%252C_&usg=__z1LHrKIgEuLZKQULqMsnK80h7wQ%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin4bOe7aTZAhVF8GMKHRweAIkQ9QEILTAB#imgrc=m0gdKii2vFsTjM:)（neko no kubikazari) you'll find loads of results.

In the future, if you ask a question here, please try to show some prior research and your best attempt at a translation. Otherwise, your post will likely be flagged.